# Line breaks in CKAN markdown with HTML

Tags: ckan

We are seeing differences in the markdown rendering between two versions of CKAN.

Using the following content in a description field. Note we have `allow_html = True` for the markdown renderer.

```
##Header
<p>
Line1

Line2
</p>
```

In 2.8.10 we see a line break between the two text lines.

e.g.

[image]

In 2.10.1, the text is both on the same line

e.g.

[image]

Does anyone know of a CKAN setting or change we can make to allow the markdown version that shows the line breaks? There was an update to the python markdown library that is used in CKAN, but we would rather not try and change that directly, i.e. would prefer a CKAN setting.